# GCP list projects wtih Golang API

Tags: api, go, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers

I am trying to learn more Go, and my first program is to list all the projects in our GCP org (API equivalent of `gcloud projects list`). Later I want to take this as a springboard to create machine images when a Compute Engine label is updated.

I am using this boilplate from the Google API docs:

"ListProjects lists projects that are direct children of the specified folder or organization resource."

```
package main

import (
        resourcemanager "cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3"
        "context"
        "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
        resourcemanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/resourcemanager/v3"
)

func main() {
        ctx := context.Background()
        c, err := resourcemanager.NewProjectsClient(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                // TODO: Handle error.
        }
        defer c.Close()

        req := &resourcemanagerpb.ListProjectsRequest{
                // TODO: Fill request struct fields.
                // See https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/resourcemanager/v3#ListProjectsRequest.
        }
        it := c.ListProjects(ctx, req)
        for {
                resp, err := it.Next()
                if err == iterator.Done {
                        break
                }
                if err != nil {
                        // TODO: Handle error.
                }
                // TODO: Use resp.
                _ = resp
        }
}
```

I realize there are "TODO" pieces here that I don't have completed. Can someone help to suggest how I can take this boilplate and get a simple list of projects? It feels like I am lacking some form of identifying my org or my project, but since I want the entire list of projects, it seems like I am not conveying my org id in the API call?

For now I am getting "PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission".  However, I know that I have Google Application Default credentials setup because I can do another API call in go to list compute instances.

Comment: First, you must auth your code so that it can invoke Google Cloud services such as Cloud Resource Manager. A good way to do this is to use a Google mechanism called "Application Default Credentials" or ADC. Google has updated its documentation recently and hidden the really good summary that it used to have for this! I recommend Googling to understand it. You will need to create a Service Account, use IAM to set the correct role (so that you can list projects), (for development purposes) create a Service Account key and then `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json`.

Comment: I've written about Application Default Credentials (ADC) on here many times, you can look through these [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A609290+%22Application+Default+Credentials%22) for some help. [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) blogs about ADC too. Although for Python, [this](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/) is a good explanation.

Comment: Originally Google Cloud's top-level resource was the Project. To accommodate organizational needs, Google added Organizations and Folders but this complicated the previously flat Project list. Now Projects may exist under an Organization (directly) or under a Folder (under an Organization **or** another Folder). So, enumerating all Projects became more complicated. This is explained succinctly under Cloud Resource Manager documentation for [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list). You must descend through a hierarchy recursively to list all

Comment: I apologize, I forgot that there's now a simpler API method to [search](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search) (!) for the projects for which an identity has permission. This is an easier way to enumerate Projects in an Organization/Folder hierarchy. You can also set `parent:organizations/{org}` to limit the search to a specific organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for Cloud Resource Manager API v3 [`projects.search`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search)

```bash
ORGANIZATION=[[YOUR-ORG]]
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]] # Service Accounts are owned by Projects
ACCOUNT="tester"

# Enable Cloud Resource Manager API in a Project
# This Project will own the Service Account too
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create the Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
 
# Create a Service Account Key locally
# For testing purposes only
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT} 

# Ensure the Service Account can browse the Organization's resources 
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding ${ORGANIZATION} \
--role=roles/browser \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL}
 
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
export ORGANIZATION

go run .
```

And:
`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    resourcemanager "cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3"
    resourcemanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/resourcemanager/v3"

    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

func main() {
    organization := os.Getenv("ORGANIZATION")
    if organization == "" {
        log.Fatalf("unable to obtain ORGANIZATION from the environment")
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := resourcemanager.NewProjectsClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    rqst := &resourcemanagerpb.SearchProjectsRequest{
        Query: fmt.Sprintf("parent:organizations/%s", organization),
    }
    it := c.SearchProjects(ctx, rqst)
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Println(resp.DisplayName)
    }

}
```